# Can someone tell me what wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to

- Create json object
- Declare the products array in a json object
- Create five json object in array
- Each json object contains following keys

  1. p_id
  2. p_name
  3. p_cost

However, I'm not getting the output result.

```js
var data = {
  "products": [{
    "p_id": 111,
    "p_name": "p_one",
    "p_cost": 100
  }];
};
var results = "";
for (var i = 0, i < data.products.length) {
  var obj = data.products[i];
  var _pid = obj.p_id;
  var _pname = obj.p_name;
  var _cost = obj.p_cost;
  results = _pid + "." + _pname + "." + _pcost + "<br>";
}
console.log(results);
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: I am not getting the output result

Comment: Does anything appear in your console error log?

Comment: Yes "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;"

Comment: Your loop should be `for (var i = 0; i < data.products.length; i++) {`

Comment: And please, when you are posting a question, provide us with the code you're using and the error details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript 101, check your console for errors, there are a few:

- extra `;` inside json
- undefined `_pcost` which should be `_cost`
- unfinished/incorrect `for` loop: `;` instead of `,` inside for loops in JavaScript, + the iteration counter missing

```js
var data = {
  "products": [{
    "p_id": 111,
    "p_name": "p_one",
    "p_cost": 100
  }]
};
var results = "";
for (var i = 0; i < data.products.length; i++) {
  var obj = data.products[i];
  var _pid = obj.p_id;
  var _pname = obj.p_name;
  var _cost = obj.p_cost;
  results = _pid + "." + _pname + "." + _cost + "<br>";
}
console.log(results)
```